Почему PySide6 так плохо конвертирует в Python?
хочу создать проект с пользовательским интерфейсом на PySide6, но когда я пытаюсь конвертировать .ui в .py графический интерфейс ломается, хотя в QtDesigner все нормально. Правая и левая панель были преобразованы в QFrame чтобы они не изменялись при изменении разрешения окна.
Я только новичек в Qt поэтому прошу без негатива. Заранее спасибо  <3
P.S. в предпросмотре так-же как и в QtDesigner.
P.S.S Левая панель тоже ломается



Мне надо было обновить PySide6, т.к. у меня стояла старая версия:
$ pip install --upgrade PySide6

